# how to redirect to url with node js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to do a node js project where a pseudo-login page communicate with mongooseDB and redirect in different pages based on username. The problem is: when I click on login button, this don't redirect me to any page (in inspect page-> network, I can see the corect response but nothing happen)

**login.html**

```
...
<form action="/dashboard" method="post" name="loginform" id="loginform">
        <span>Inserisci i seguenti dati per accedere:</span><br><br>
        <span>Username: </span>
        <span id="username"></span>
        <input name="nome" id="usernameuser"/><br><br>
  
        <span> Password: </span>
        <span id="userpassword"></span>
        <input name="password" id="passworduser" type="password"/><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login"/>

</form>

<script>
    const form = document.getElementById('loginform');
    form.addEventListener('submit',loginUser);

    async function loginUser(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      const username = document.getElementById('usernameuser').value;
     
      const password = document.getElementById('passworduser').value;
      if(username=='admin' && password==='admin'){
        window.location.href='/libri/list';
      }else{
        const result = await fetch('/login',{
          method: 'POST',
          headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username,
            password
          })
        }).then((res)=>res.json())
      }
    }
    
</script>
...
```

***login.js***

```
...
router.post('/', async (req,res)=>{
    
      const username= req.body.username;
      const password= req.body.password;
    
   
    const utente = await User.findOne({ username }).lean()
    if (!utente) {
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }

    if (password==utente.password) {
        // the username, password combination is successful

        const token = jwt.sign(
            {
                id: utente._id,
                username: utente.username
            },
            JWT_SECRET
        )
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }
});
...
```

Can you explain me the problem and an idea of solution?

Comment: When you inspect the network, did you lookup for the `redirect` header in the response?

Comment: ***GENERAL:***
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/dashboard
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 Not Modified
Remote Address: [::1]:8000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

***HEADER RESPONSE:***
Content-Length: 2681
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 28 Nov 2020 21:45:56 GMT
ETag: W/"a79-LtugjJNig5w8VM7+WSblzSJ7Gps"
X-Powered-By: Express

Comment: It seems like the response sending the dashboard HTML but not redirects. you can check if it's true?

Comment: Yes but I can't understand why. I'm working on this from 5 days

Comment: Hi, does it still an open subject?

Comment: I solved transfrming login.html in login.hbs, removing script and mostly the fetch function. In this way i simply do the render instead the redirect and works. So i think that the problem is the fetch function that conflict with the res.redirect

Comment: For fun, make the request without fetch, with a simple XML Request approach.

Comment: the url in your fetch ("/login") does not correspond to the router endpoint ("/"). Did you  `mount` that endpoint?

Comment: also I do not follow your logic - if the user is not found, you use redirect. If it is found and username and password match, you redirect anyway.

Comment: @rags2riches yes is a "fake login"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using your fetch this way:

```js
fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      .
      .
      .
      redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
      referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer'// no-referrer, *client
});
```

Set the `redirect` attribute in your options.
Let me know if it helps :)